# SvcUtil /edb doesn't generate INotifyPropertyChange when DotNET 4.5 is installed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

All of the dev computers here but one has DotNET 4.5 installed. The last one has 4.0 installed. Only the one with 4.0 generates proxy classes that implements INotifyPropertyChange, all other computers doesn't.

According to MSDN /edb is supported.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx

The switches we are using is: /o /ct /r / edb / n /noconfig /tcv

This is generated from the 4.0 computer:

```
public partial class OrganizationEdition : MyCompany.MyProject.Client.Win.ServiceProxy.UpdateableEntity, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string CommentField;

    private System.DateTime ValidFromField;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidToField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Comment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CommentField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.Equals(this.CommentField, value) != true))
            {
                this.CommentField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Comment");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is from a 4.5 computer (with Windows SDK 7.0A):

```
public partial class OrganizationEdition : MyCompany.MyProject.Client.Win.ServiceProxy.UpdateableEntity
{

    private string CommentField;

    private System.DateTime ValidFromField;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidToField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Comment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CommentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.CommentField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you why it is not working.

However I could give you a trick how to get around this. You could use **.tt** files (T4 templates) in order to restore missing notifications in property setters in particular classes existing in your solution at compile time.

An example of how to implement such functionality is avaliable [here on Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=dustin-davis&name=t4-m05-real-world-examples&mode=live&clip=4&course=t4-templates) and [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) is more information about T4 templates syntax.

Comment: Creating a proxy template from scratch isn't trivial. Unless one can find a template to use as a starting point, using T4 doesn't really help

Comment: The idea is not about creating new proxies from scratch. It is about creating a T4 template that will use Visual Studio items such as solutions, projects, files in order to find proxies and modify their  properties implementation at compile time through reflection so that they will implement missing changing notifications.

Comment: Been there, done that, parsed the XSD, generated the files. Unless you have a template already, it will take days to create one from scratch